# How to create a select box field to select from a filtered list of articles?

Tags: entities

[image]

in this example, I want to make the select box to select from a filtered list of articles.

What is the proper way to customize the options available in this select box ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Step 1

To have such a list of articles that can be referenced, you should ***first*** (repeat: ***first***) create a view (with the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module) to create a list of all the articles that are allowed to be selected. And the display type of such view must be an *Entity Reference* display.

#### Step 2

Your select box field (to select from a filtered list of articles) should be field that looks like so:

- Field Name = Anything you want, eg `field_articles_list`.
- Field Type = Entity Reference, using these additional settings for it:

  - *Target type* = `node`
  - *Number of values* = `1` (probably, though something like "unlimited may do as well).
  - "Mode" (within "entity selection") = `Views: Filter by an entity reference view`. However, before you can select an appropriate view at this point (which is eligible to do so), you first need to create a view with an *Entity Reference* display, or add such a display to an existing view. In your case, you should select the view created in "Step 1".
  - Pick any of the other options to define this field as you see fit.

Comment: hi. I finally have the time to do what you say. It works! Million Thanks! screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/i8IJHSf.png

Comment: @JacobGoh merci for the update (and the accept) ... interesting image also (though I don't really understand the "select list options" it shows, but I trust it works for you). Next question?